# How can i disable the next button in last image on html5 lightbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I want to disable the next button in the last image of my html5 lightbox, because it's automatically redirecting to the other categories which I don't want to show.

Here is my code:

```
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-6">
    <div class="story">
        <a href="panic.html" class="html5lightbox" data-group="set1"><img src="images/works/panic1.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive hvr_img"></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Where exactly is the button? Is panic1.jpg your "Button"?

Comment: Better post some more details

Comment: Actually html5lightbox plugin is showing the next button. I just need to call the class 'html5lightbox' only because i have installed the html5lightbox library.

Comment: http://harryandlouit.com/web/. This is the beta version of my current project.

Comment: This project has many categories which having corresponding galleries. So i used html5lightbox plugin to show the galleries which pop up when click on corresponding featured images ( The plugin has next and previous navigation and a close button ). But this navigation automatically redirect to the next category div which also has the plugin class and that i don't want. I want to hide the navigation after each category or on the last image of a category so that it can't navigate to the next div.